# WhatsApp not launching after Windows + App Update

Tags: whatsapp

Yesterday my Lumia 640 Dual Sim updated to Windows Phone 10.0.15063.251 and today WhatsApp installed an update.

When I attempt to launch WhatsApp, I am taken back to the phone's home screen immediately. However, the app seems to work in the background, as I continue to receive the WhatsApp notifications at the top of the screen.

*Every time* I reboot my phone, the following message is displayed at the top of the screen (translated below):

**Willkommen zu Nachrichten+**
Eine bessere Möglichkeit, SMS zu schreiben, zu chatten und Inhalte zu teilen

**Welcome to Messages+**
A better possibility to write text messages, chat and share content

I think that the message comes from [this app](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/store/p/nachrichten/9wzdncrdr120). However, the app is nowhere to be found in the list of installed apps and I still have the old Message app with the same tile icon as before.

Any suggestions how to fix the problem are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered as Guest a few days ago, but my answer disapeared. So i'll write again. Simple uninstall of whatsapp solved the problem. After new install whatsapp prompted me to use the Backup (which was made by whatsapp without the winphone backup).
After backup reinstall everthing was working. 
But i didn't find the possibility to uncheck whatsapps charing data with facebook. So they got me..
Jens

Comment: I deleted two of your answers to this question because they looked like "I have this/related problem"-type comments, which [are not allowed here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). I see now your second post actually contained an answer to the original question. Sorry for deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

That's an app crash and seems like either the new WhatsApp update has a bug that crashes or the OS is experiencing an issue.

Although it is less likely to work, I suggest you try soft resetting your device. It won't harm your data and is similar to a simple restart with refreshed RAM. You can do that by holding Volume Up + Power button at the same time for about 10-15 seconds. If this doesn't work then you'd have to report this issue to WhatsApp and look for the future updates until it get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions. In the end, I had to reinstall WhatsApp to launch it again (the most recent backup was a couple days old, but successfully imported).

I still get the funky Messages+ notifications at restart, but I'll live with it for the time being. Should it become a bigger issue in the future, I will soft reset the phone.

Thanks again.